# display all facebook statuses with api?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

I am trying to get the hang of the facebook API. I want to be able to retrieve all the statuses I posted. Eventually I want to retrieve all the statuses I posted and see who liked each status.. Because my ultimate goal is to see how many statuses this one girl liked of mine.  (Yes, I have a facebook stalker and I'm trying to use my programming skills to track it, ha ha.)

Right now I have set up the facebook api and I am able to get my basic profile information, but I'm stuck there. I tried searching here and on the web and it hasn't work, i'm not sure if they're outdated.

This is what I have so far just to show my basic information (excluding the typical stuff like including the facebook.php, API Key, and Secret Key):

```
$user_profile = $facebook->api('/me');
print_r($user_profile);
```

So if anyone can tell me how to pull my status updates that'll be great! then i'll just have to figure out how to pull the likes from each of those status...

cheers

**EDIT:**
I did more research and looked at the facebook developer articles.. So far I have this:

```
$get_status = $facebook->api('/me?fields=statuses');
print_r($get_status);
```

When I use "/me?fields=statuses" in Facebook's Graph API Explorer it shows all my statuses, but when I use it in PHP on my script that I'm trying to get working it only shows MY facebook ID (the one I'm logged in under). Why is this the case?

Answer (score 0):

```
$Status = $facebook->api('/me/feed/');
print_r($Status);
```

Comment: senthilbp, thanks for your help but that doesn't work. that just shows the latest wall post, it shows a post that I put on a girl's wall for her birthday instead of showing a status I posted. I edited my original post on here but I'm still having trouble. @senthilbp

Comment: Did you give "read_stream" permission , pls update your complete code in your question

Comment: I just realized you are correct, the permission is not set. how do i go about setting it? In the graph api explorer I just unchecked the permission and i got the same result as my code, only my profile ID, so I assume I just need to get permission for my code. how do i do this?

Comment: set permission in your login URL $params = array(
  'scope' => 'read_stream, friends_likes',

);

$loginUrl = $facebook->getLoginUrl($params);